# Iframe cannot be accessed with test automation

Tags: selenium, iframe, automation, webdriver, http-status-code-403

I'm trying to automate a website test with Selenium. In this feature, I want to go to the site's payment area, open the payment form and check if all necessary elements are there.

It worked fine some time ago but now during the automation, where the payment form should be it just says 403 Forbidden: You don't have permission to access /index.php on this server. I don't understand that as the test is not manually going to the url, it just clicks a button and then the payment iframe should load. I tried opening the iframe src directly, with the same result. However manually it works. It only fails when automated.

Does anybody know what the reason might be?

Comment: Are you running remote or locally? Also on manual are you ever used any user-password?

Comment: Solved the 'problem', it was caused by a wrong char in the user agent we used in behat.yml... the payment iframe used this user agent and couldn't handle it.

Comment: You can add this as an answer and accept it :)